# If $N$ is a natural transformation between $Id_\mathscr{C}$ to $F: \mathscr{C} \to \mathscr{C}$ , then is $F \circ N=N \circ F$?

Tags: category-theory

In the above setting, let  $X \in \mathscr{C}$ be an object in the category $\mathscr{C}$, $F: \mathscr{C} \to \mathscr{C}$ a functor, and let $N: F \to Id_\mathscr{C}$ be a natural transformation.  By definition, associated to any morphism $f: X \to Y$ with $X,Y \in \mathscr{C}$ there is a commutative diagram $N_{Y}\circ Id(f)=F(f)\circ N_X$. In particular, associated to a clever choice of a morphism $N_X: Id(X) \to F(X)$ there is a commutative diagram  $N_{F(X)}\circ Id(N_X)=F(N_X)\circ N_X$. Thus $N_{F(X)}\circ Id(N_X)=F(N_X)\circ N_X$. This prompts us to ask  if $N_{F(X)}=F(N_X)$  and it makes sense to ask this since both morphisms are arrows from $F(x) \to F^2(X)$. In other words are the following compositions of functors with natural transformations $F \circ  N=N \circ F$ the same?

Now if $F,G: \mathscr{C} \to \mathscr{C}$ commute and $N: F \to G$, then it still makes sense to ask whether $F \circ N = N \circ F$.  If I try to show this by mimicking the argument above I get $N_{F(x)} \circ G(N_X)=F(N_X) \circ N_{G(X)}$.  This doesn't get me anywhere near showing $F \circ N = N \circ F$.  When is  $F \circ N = N \circ F$ in this setting?

Edit: I tried clarifying and salvaging the post.

Comment: Just some thoughts on your first paragraph. Natural transformations are between functors, so your $N$ should probably mention $F$ in it's type instead of $X$. Naturality involves considering any $f : a \to b$, and your naturality statement mentions no such morphisms; consider looking up the definition. You restrict your morphisms along images and those are ill-formed constructions in arbitrary categories. Do you mean to use $\mathcal{Set}$, the category of sets and functions?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do the statements read okay now, in general?